# Add USB Keyboard to Sheevaplug (Debian 2.6)?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, sheevaplug

Totally unfamiliar with Linux, I try to **add a USB keyboard to a Sheevaplug** headless ARM computer running **Linux debian 2.6.22.18**

Accessing the Sheevaplug from a shell (remote, via Ethernet) ...

```
login as: root
root@192.168.20.108's password:
Linux debian 2.6.22.18 #1 Thu Mar 19 14:46:22 IST 2009 armv5tejl

root@debian:~#
```

... the (local) USB keyboard seems to have been recognized ...

```
root@debian:~# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046a Product=0023 Version=0111
N: Name="HID 046a:0023"
P: Phys=usb-ehci_marvell.70059-1/input0
S: Sysfs=/class/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd
B: EV=120003
B: KEY=7 ff800000 7ff e0b2ffdf 1cfffff ffffffff fffffffe
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=046a Product=0023 Version=0111
N: Name="HID 046a:0023"
P: Phys=usb-ehci_marvell.70059-1/input1
S: Sysfs=/class/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd
B: EV=f
B: KEY=7fff 2c3027 bf004440 0 0 1 f80 8837c400 667bfa d971dfed 9e0000 0 0 0
B: REL=40
B: ABS=1 0

root@debian:~#
```

... but pressing keys on the local USB keyboard does not display anything ...

```
root@debian:~#
```

Any Ideas?

Regards,
tamberg

Comment: The sheeva plug is a fairly oddball device; adding more information about your setup (especially a description of the plug) would help a lot.  I, for one, was under the impression that the sheeva plug didn't actually have a local display.

From what I can infer, you've got a plug computer that you've accessed via a remote shell over a LAN.  You've attached a usb keyboard to the plug, and are trying to get the commands from the local keyboard to the remote shell.  Is this an accurate picture?

Comment: Exactly. Getting commands (or any text) from the local keyboard to the shell (as a proof of concept), and later to a program running on the Sheevaplug.

Comment: Why would you expect keystrokes on a local shell to show up in a remote shell? This is not how it works on any system. You would need to attach a display to the sheeva plug in order to use a local shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default local input does not show up in the remote shell. As stated in

[Linux: Redirect Local USB Keyboard To Remote Shell](https://superuser.com/questions/92147/linux-redirect-local-usb-keyboard-to-remote-shell)

a simple way to check from the remote shell that the local USB keyboard works is

```
cat /dev/tty0
```

Regards,
tamberg

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect keystrokes on a local shell to show up in a remote shell? This is not how it works on any system. You would need to attach a display to the sheeva plug in order to use a local shell. I don't think this has anything to do with the drivers being loaded and everything to do with misunderstanding how the shell works.

Comment: Good point, thanks. As there is no display I'll try to write a program reading keyboard input (from stdin?) into a file. Run that in the background (with screen?) and see what's there afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought:

The latest version of the kernel is 2.6.32, therefore 2.6.22 seems a little old, *or was that a typo?*

I don't recall *when* USB keyboard support was added to the kernel, I simply know it's a relatively recent thing.

This may be nothing to do with your keyboard problem, but I notice

```
P: Phys=usb-ehci_marvell.70059-1/input0
```

in your question. I remember having trouble with a USB2.0 external HDD at about the time of 2.6.22 and it was necessary to use `insmod` to load an 'ehci' kernel module before it would run at usb2.0 speed.

EDIT: I found a [Linux USB FAQ](http://www.linux-usb.org/FAQ.html) which included the following:

> If you are using Linux 2.4, don't
>   expect community assistance unless you
>   first upgrade to a recent 2.6 kernel.
>   If you're using any kernel that old,
>   you should probably have some sort of
>   vendor support agreement to handle
>   issues that come up. If you are using
>   UHCI on a 2.4 kernel, try to reproduce
>   the problem with the "other" UHCI host
>   controller driver (HCD). There are
>   currently two UHCI drivers, which
>   don't always behave the same: usb-uhci
>   and uhci (the "alt" or "JE" driver).
>   If you find that you have a
>   workaround, please still report the
>   problem! And make sure you say which
>   HCD(s) you're using.
>
> Q: How do I make USB be detected on my
>   machine?
>
> A: If you are sure that you actually
>   have a suitable hardware setup, look
>   for a BIOS option that could be
>   applicable. It might be labelled as
>   USB, or it might be more obscure,
>   discussing Plug-n-Play, or having
>   options for various types of operating
>   systems. You may need to try various
>   combinations. Unless you rely on a USB
>   keyboard or mouse during booting, it's
>   probably safest to disable support for
>   those in your BIOS; lots of BIOS
>   writers seem to get that wrong, making
>   trouble when Linux tries to take over
>   USB.

Hmmm, still talks about UHCI. I wish it was a bit more specific than 'recent 2.6 kernel'

There is a suggestion [here](http://forum.kernelnewbies.org/read.php?10,873,873) that kernels 2.6.23.x up to 2.6.28.x are needed. But, again, it's vague.

Comment: No typo. How can I check if keyboards are supported?

Comment: Thanks for the edit (+1). From the kernel log it looked like an ehci module is loaded. At least that's what I remember. Got to check that tomorrow.

Comment: I found out USB keyboards were supported on my PC by the same method you were hoping to use. I plugged one in and (was surprised when) it worked.