# Linux: Redirect Local USB Keyboard To Remote Shell

Tags: linux, usb, sheevaplug

(Discalimer: totally unfamiliar with Linux)

Is there a way to redirect the local standard input (USB keyboard plugged into a headless, ARM-based Sheevaplug running Linux debian 2.6.22.18) to a remote SSH shell (WinXP/Putty, connected via Ethernet)?

Regards,
tamberg

Comment: I'm not clear on what you expect this to do... it might be possible.

Comment: Trying to test if my local USB keyboard works at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  As root:

```
cat /dev/tty0
```

Type a few characters, you should get gibberish out.  Press Control-C from the SSH session to stop it, and if the terminal is messed up do a

```
eval `reset`
```

to fix it.